# Firebase storage images aren't being downloaded on iOS (Fine in Unity editor and android)

Tags: xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

Images aren't being downloaded using Firebase Storage to iOS platform. Currently working fine in the editor and android build. I can't seem to find anything online about it or any solution!

Getting a few warnings and errors in Xcode when testing on iPhone.

Most noticeable error is: 
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002

I've already appended to the Plist file to remove the warning and that doesn't seem to do anything.

Most noticeable warning is: 
"You are using download over http. Currently Unity adds NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Info.plist to simplify transition, but it will be removed soon. Please consider updating to https."

`The File 1. Southern carmine bee-eater.jpg did not exist on our machine, Start the download process from Firebase 
 Full file location is  /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1B4D89BB-2DA5-491B-927F-8B6E1B8CDB18/Documents/1. Southern carmine bee-eater.jpg - If this is a Low res image make sure it is named the same it is on firebase to stop the needed for changes in the app control panel
<DownloadAllFiles>d__20:MoveNext()
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)`

`2019-03-30 00:36:39.227453+0000 krugerexplorer[23609:7864992] You are using download over http. Currently Unity adds NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Info.plist to simplify transition, but it will be removed soon. Please consider updating to https.
2019-03-30 00:36:39.228999+0000 krugerexplorer[23609:7864959] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002
2019-03-30 00:36:39.230999+0000 krugerexplorer[23609:7864993] You are using download over http. Currently Unity adds NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Info.plist to simplify transition, but it will be removed soon. Please consider updating to https.
2019-03-30 00:36:39.231672+0000 krugerexplorer[23609:7864948] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002
2019-03-30 00:36:39.240721+0000 krugerexplorer[23609:7864994] You are using download over http. Currently Unity adds NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Info.plist to simplify transition, but it will be removed soon. Please consider updating to https.`

Comment: and did you try to use `https`?

Comment: @derHugo I don't think you get much of a choice. You just get whatever methods come with the SDK.

I've also tried the advice given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47865375

No joy.